# Is it possible to share data from database to facebook using facebook integration,If yes how it is possible

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

Is it possible to share data from database to facebook using facebook integration,If yes how it is possible.

```
if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Facebook"]) {
    SLComposeViewController* composeView = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [composeView setInitialText:finalDesc];

    [self presentViewController:composeView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Please some one help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to pre-fill a Facebook message, [see this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill) for more information. 
In detail it's not allowed to:

> Pre-fill the user message parameter with any content the user didn't enter themselves, even if they can edit or delete that content before sharing. This applies to posts, comments, photo captions, and photo album captions.